# How to transform postfix_expression in ANTLR C grammar to AST?

Tags: c, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I'm learning ANTLR by modifying the C grammar and trying something interests myself. The C grammar I started with is from: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153358328744/C.g

Now I want to transform `postfix_expression` to its corresponding AST but haven't known anything related to the transformation of the form `xx (aa|bb|cc)* yy`

```
...
unary_expression
  : postfix_expression
  | unary_operator^ unary_expression
  ;

postfix_expression
  : primary_expression
  ( '[' expression ']'
  | '(' ')'
  | '(' argument_expression_list ')'
  | '.' ID
  )*
  ;

unary_operator
  : '+'
  | '-'
  | '~'
  | '!'
  ;
...
```

Can you help me with this problem? You may just add some `^` and/or `!` notations to the `postfix_expression` part in the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id'd go for something like this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  MEMBER;
  INDEX;
  CALL;
}

parse
  :  unary_expression EOF -> ^(ROOT unary_expression)
  ;

unary_expression
  :  postfix_expression
  |  unary_operator unary_expression -> ^(unary_operator unary_expression)
  ;

postfix_expression
  :  primary_expression tail* -> ^(primary_expression tail*)
  ;

tail
  :  '[' expression ']'                -> ^(INDEX expression)
  |  '(' argument_expression_list? ')' -> ^(CALL argument_expression_list?)
  |  '.' ID                            -> ^(MEMBER ID)
  ;

primary_expression
  :  ID
  |  '(' expression ')' -> expression
  ;

argument_expression_list
  :  expression (',' expression)* -> expression+
  ;

unary_operator
  :  '+'
  |  '-'
  |  '~'
  |  '!'
  ;

expression
  :  NUMBER
  |  ID
  ;

NUMBER : '0'..'9'+;
ID     : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

which will parse the input:

```
a.b.c(foo,42)[123]
```

into the following AST:

[image]

making it easy to evaluate the expression left to right.